# phpstorm empty Quick documentation lookup window

Tags: php, phpstorm

If I want to read the PHPDoc of a function/class in PHPStorm, I hover the cursor over the name. Unfortunately all I get is an empty window.

Any idea what's missing?

[image]

Comment: It does not look like it's empty -- more like wrong window size -- resize it manually.

Comment: Bingo! If all problems are that easy to solve, live would be easy.

Comment: Please add your comment as annswer in order I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on screenshot: it does not looks like it's empty -- more like wrong window size (for whatever reason). Resize it manually.