# PhpStorm quick documentation window always minimized

Tags: php, phpstorm

My colleagues and I are using the "Show quick documentation on mouse move" option in PhpStorm 8.0.3. We keep having the problem that the window is shown empty (see [phpstorm empty Quick documentation lookup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183321/phpstorm-empty-quick-documentation-lookup-window)). We already figured out it's only minimized and can be resized to show the desired information.

The problem is it won't remember the increased size. It may remember its new size for a few minutes, but some unknown circumstances limit it to that. 5 minutes later on a different file it would be needed to resize again and another 5 minutes later again. This makes it a pretty annoying procedure.

How can I get PhpStorm to remember the window size? (or render a decent size automatically every time).

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: Does this happens in every project or in this specific project only?

Comment: We are mainly working on one single project so can't say much about other projects.

Comment: Well ... nothing specific comes into my mind .. except, maybe, that you may be using multiple monitors and it somehow screws the things.

Comment: In any case, try this. 1) Close IDE; 2) open `project/.idea/workspace.xml` file in any plain text editor; 3) find all lines that start with `<window_info id="Documentation"` and delete them -- should be 2 matches (make backup copy of the whole folder first, of course) 4) Do the same in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80\config\options\window.manager.xml` file (that's for Windows 7; [another OS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)); 5) Launch IDE

Comment: I will try that. I only had one entry in workspace.xml (but several workspace<random numbers>.xml files?) and none in window.manager.xml though. I moved the numbered workspace files away and deleted the window entry in the remaining one, will try this out a while :-) thx.

Comment: @LazyOne unfortunately it did not help. Right now I have 1 workspace.xml and 2 workspace.xml.<random number>. None of them contains the <window_info id="Documentation" line, neither the window.manager.xml. And PhpStorms keeps forgetting. :-(

Comment: 1) Have no clue what `workspace.xml.<random number>` could be (unless it's a "safe-write" copies that for some reason were not deleted) -- my guess that they can be safely deleted. 2) No other ideas except trying from scratch (backup and delete IDE whole IDE settings folder e.g. `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80` for Windows 7) -- you can always restore it from backup. **In any case:** what OS and Java do you use?

Comment: Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64 bit and Java 1.7.0_79.

Comment: @LazyOne I deleted the .WebIde80 folder and had to redo many settings. After one day, the popups were minimized again. So no solution in sight. :-(

Comment: This could be Linux specific issue (most likely). My best advice under such circumstances (when nothing that I could this of helps) -- file a ticket to their Issue Tracker and provide your `idea.log` (Help| Show Log in...): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: It was fixed in one of the last releases!